# PhotoUrl from Firebase Database display in CoverFlow

Tags: ios, swift, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating an app where users will be able to post pictures and scroll in a coverFlow using the library "iCarousel".
But the code doesn´t show me any pictures from my database.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, iCarouselDataSource, iCarouselDelegate {
    var imageArray : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let database = Database.database().reference()
        let tempImageRef = database.child("posts").child("photoUrl")
        imageArray = ["photo1", "photo2", "photo1", "photo2", "photo1"]

        carouselView.type = iCarouselType.coverFlow
        carouselView.reloadData()

        func numberOfItemsInCarousel(carousel: iCarousel) -> Int {
            return imageArray.count
        }

        func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, viewForItemAt index: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {

            var imageView : UIImageView!

            if view == nil {
                imageView  = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))
                imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            } else {
                imageView = view as! UIImageView
            }

            imageView.image = UIImage(named: "\(imageArray.object(at: index))")
            return imageView
        }
    }

    func numberOfItems(in carousel: iCarousel) -> Int {
        return imageArray.count
    }

    func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, viewForItemAt index: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
        var imageView : UIImageView!

        if view == nil {
            imageView  = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 250))
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        } else {
            imageView = view as! UIImageView
        }

        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "\(imageArray.object(at: index))")
        return imageView
    }

    @IBOutlet var carouselView: iCarousel!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageViewer: UIImageView!
}
```

Comment: Why are there carousel delegate and data source functions inside `viewDidLoad`? That won't work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any place in your code where you fetch the photoUrls from your Firebase database, nor do I see any place where you are attempting to download the data at that url and convert it to a UIImage.  Using the `UIImage(named: ...` initializer only works for images in the bundle.

So, first, you need to get all the imageUrls.  You have many options, but this is one:

```
self.tempImageRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
  //I'm just assuming your urls are an array of strings, so change this if that's not the case.
  if let urls = snapshot.value as? [String] {
    //Save the fetched urls to your imageArray
    self.imageArray = urls
  }
}
```

Now that you have the imageUrls, you can use them in your carousel.  Again, many options, but here's one:

```
func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, viewForItemAt index: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
  //Get a reference to the imageUrl at this index
  let imageUrl = self.imageArray[index]
  //Create a URL from the string
  let url = URL(string: imageUrl)!
  //Create a URLRequest and set the HTTP method to GET
  var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
  urlRequest.httpMethod = "GET"
  //Create URLSession to handle the request
  let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
  session.dataTask(with: URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
    //Check to make sure you got data back, and that you can convert it to a usable UIImage
    if let imgData = data, let img = UIImage(data: imgData) {
      //Assign the image to your imageView
      imageView.image = img
    }
  }).resume()
}
```

This does not include all of the safe optional-unwrapping that you should be doing with Swift, nor does it handle the operation queue management that is necessary to avoid locking up your UI.  Make sure to look into it if you aren't already familiar.

Also worth noting: many people use the super popular third-party cocoapod SDWebImage to handle the downloading of the data.  You might want to read about this if you're going to be doing a lot of downloading/assigning from your Firebase db to your UIImageViews.